# WPF Adding a custom property in a control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, properties, custom-controls

Ok i have a WPF application in which i have a resource dictionary. In the dictionary i have a new style for a `Button` that looks like this :

```
    <Style x:Key="MenuButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
      <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">

                <Grid>
                    <Image x:Name="Imager" RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality" Width="{TemplateBinding Width}"  Height="{TemplateBinding Height}" Source="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Tag}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
                </Grid>

                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                        <Setter TargetName="Imager" Property="Width" Value="24" />
                        <Setter TargetName="Imager" Property="Height" Value="24" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                        <Setter TargetName="Imager" Property="Width" Value="16" />
                        <Setter TargetName="Imager" Property="Height" Value="16" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

And use this stye in my XAML like this :

```
<Button x:Name="Home" Style="{DynamicResource MenuButtonStyle}" Width="20" Height="20" Tag="\Images\Home.png"/>
<Button x:Name="Settings" Style="{DynamicResource MenuButtonStyle}" Width="20" Height="20" Tag="\Images\Settings.png"/>
```

Now what i want to do is, Create a new property in the `Button` style named `OverWidth` and `OverHeight` in order to use it like this :

```
<Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
   <Setter TargetName="Imager" Property="Width" Value= OVERWIDTH/>
   <Setter TargetName="Imager" Property="Height" Value= OVERHEIGHT/>
</Trigger>
```

And in XAML :

```
<Button x:Name="Home" Style="{DynamicResource MenuButtonStyle}" Width="20" Height="20" Tag="\Images\Home.png" OVERWIDTH = "24"/>
```

I dont even know if this is possible. I dont want to use `Binding SomeIntenger`from C# code.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can use the [attached properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011.aspx):

```
public class Extensions
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty OverWidthProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("OverWidth", typeof(double), typeof(Extensions), new PropertyMetadata(default(double)));

    public static void SetOverWidth(UIElement element, double value)
    {
        element.SetValue(OverWidthProperty, value);
    }

    public static double GetOverWidth(UIElement element)
    {
        return (double)element.GetValue(OverWidthProperty);
    }
}
```

Xaml:

```
xmlns:extensions="clr-namespace:NAMESPACE FOR Extensions class"

<Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="{Binding Path=(extensions:Extensions.OverWidth), RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
</Trigger>

<Button extensions:Extensions.OverWidth="100" Width="10"/>
```

Comment: Not working for me. Im using Brush instead of double. The default metadata value is being set irrespective of the brush value set in xaml. Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 9):

I used the **Tag property**, which works very well. I can write anything on **Tag**

For example (AXML) on a **Button**:

```
<Button x:Name="Btn80" Click="eventoClick" Tag="80">Casillero 80</Button>}
```

I can use a string field to add *lists* or *values* **int**, **date**, etc to then ***interpret*** and **convert** the string into anything.

**I used this solution, due to the need to add an ID field to a button.